# How to display simple hierarchial select output as inline instead of UL

Tags: taxonomy-terms

Im using Drupal 7 with SHS, and i have a Taxonomy vocabulary "Location"

The format for this vocab is like : State > City > Location.

I have created a Page View and added the field, but the output of the field is in a UL
like

- Maharashtra
- Mumbai
- Location

However, i want it to be displayed in a single line as:

```
Maharashtra > Mumbai > Location
```

The current HTML Output of the field is: URL http://stage.adventureex.com/experience

```
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="shs-hierarchy">
<li class="shs-parent first">Maharashtra</li>
<li class="shs-parent">Pune</li>
<li class="shs-term-selected last">Junnar</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I thought i could edit shs CSS file and find a solution, but it was not resolved. Here is the shs.formatter.css file

```
/**
* @file
* Styles for formatted output of shs module.
*/

.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference ul.shs-hierarchy {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference .links ul.shs-hierarchy li {
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.field-type-taxonomy-term-reference .links ul.shs-hierarchy li.last {
  padding: 0;
}
.shs-hierarchy li:after {
  content: '>';
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.shs-hierarchy li.last:after {
  content: '';
  margin: 0;
}
```

I asked the same question at #drupal-suppor IRC and @dc2 suggested that i add the following to the css:

```
.item-list .shs-hierarchy .shs-parent{display:inline !important;}
.item-list .shs-hierarchy .shs-parent{display:inline !important;}
.item-list .shs-hierarchy .shs-term-selected{display:inline !important;}
```

This gives me the intended result, but i wanted to know if this is the recommended way OR is there a better way to do it.

As the UL and LI tags still exist in the HTML output.

Comment: Yes, CSS is the recommended way to handle the display of HTML elements. Did you have a Drupal-specific question at all or were you just looking for this general best-practice advice for CSS?

Comment: @Clive thanks, ill continue with this solution. I am using D7 with a specific Module for D7 (SHS) hence my question was specific to D7 as i thought there might be some other way to make this happen, say making some changes in the shs.module.